# WEB API + Cache all users from AD on application_start

Tags: asp.net, caching, active-directory, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WEB API which perform 2 functions

1. return current login user details
2. Also enable asyn search for any user.

In order to save performance hit on first call, i want to get all users and save them in cache on application_start. I have enabled IIS warm up, so everything should be in cache before first request

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LdapPath, activeDirectoryUserid, activeDirectoryPassword);
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
            {
                Filter = "(&(&(objectClass = user)(objectClass = person)))"
            };
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(AppConstants.AD.Name);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(AppConstants.AD.SamAccountName);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(AppConstants.AD.ThumbnailPhoto);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(AppConstants.AD.FirstName);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(AppConstants.AD.Manager);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(AppConstants.AD.DistinguishedName);
            search.CacheResults = false;

            SearchResultCollection resultset = search.FindAll();
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: added code above which i am using to get all users. this is not working.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: result set have zero records.

Comment: Do you have to use `DirectoryEntry` class?

Comment: no, if there is some alternative

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

```
using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{          
   UserPrincipal allUsers = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(allUsers);
   foreach (UserPrincipal user in ps.FindAll())
   {
     //USER will contain the necessary information you need
     string name = user.DisplayName;
   }
}
```